# How to reference the current schema in which I am in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, information-schema

I would like to know if there is some kind of variable or function that gives me the schema in where I a executing a script in POSTGRESQL.

For example, in the code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TABLE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE UPPER(TABLE_SCHEMA) = ******* 
  AND UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = 'ExampleTable'
```

I would like to change `*******` with the working schema.

Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Use `current_schema` and don't convert it to upper case. By default, names are stored in lower case in Postgres

```
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = current_schema
```

---

Note that `UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = 'ExampleTable'` will never be true. You would at least need upper on the right hand side as well `UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = upper('ExampleTable')`